# What is difference between ckanext-ngsiview and right_time_context plugin CKAN?

Tags: fiware, ckan

I had a query that what is difference in ckanext-ngsiview and ckanext-right_time_context plugin in ckan?

I was using ckanext-ngsiview of conwetlab,They have made another release and renamed it to right_time_context.

While,I was working with the latter plugin,I did'nt recieved the expected result which I used to receive with ngsiview.(Screenshot attached)

Also,do I need to enable any other  plugin for right_time_context?

[image]

After adding the id as **ngsi_view** in my (development.ini file) I get the following error as follows

[image: ckanext-right_time_context]

I am not being rendered the NGSI-VIEW after adding **right_time_context** as id in my (.ini file)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Arnav, the id of the plugin is  `right_time_context`, and this is the value you have to use to enable the plugin using the `ckan.plugins` settings. The `ngsi_view` is for enabling the view using `ckan.views.default_views`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin has evolved and is not only a view for NGSI anymore, so we think that the name was not representing the functionality. On the other hand, Telefónica has the previous name registered on pypi, so we cannot make releases using that name. Apart from that, the new version is an evolution of the previous releases we did.

That message means that there is no view configured for that resource. I guessing you are complaining because the raw NGSI view was not configured automatically (in fact this can be perfectly ok since you may want to manually add views).

To enable automatic configuration of the raw view, make sure you include the `ngsi_view` view into the `ckan.views.default_views` setting. The important detail here is that the id of the view has changed from `ngsiview` to `ngsi_view` in this new version. Take into account that this is not the id of the plugin that is `right_time_context` and this id is the one you have to use to enable the plugin using `ckan.plugins`.

> Also, do I need to enable any other plugin for right_time_context?

The `resource_proxy` plugin (comes directly with CKAN, but has to be enabled), is required for using the raw view, although it is optional if you don't need that view.

The `ckanext-oauth2` plugin is required to make request to secured Context Broker instances.

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, under what condition for right_time_context to work resource_proxy would not be required.?

Comment: The `resource_proxy` plugin has to be enabled whenever you want to use the `ngsi_view` view